# ASP.NET 5 RC1 -- Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core

After upgrading to Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2, I started getting the following error on my ASP.NET 5 RC1 application, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.  Under the old version we would use a BindingRedirect.  How do we resolve this in the new vNEXT version of ASP.NET

`` System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Add(IConfigurationProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, String path, Boolean optional)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run(Type startupType, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() ``

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to fix this issue I had to remove the WRAP / Newtonsoft.Json folder.  Apparently installing the new version created an entry for it in the WRAP folder.  Once I removed it form there, my app runs fine again.